# Handle connections to user defined DB in Django

Tags: python, django, database, postgresql, orm

I have pretty simple model. User defines url and database name for his own Postgres server. My django backend fetches some info from client DB to make some calculations, analytics and draw some graphs.
How to handle connections? Create new one when client opens a page, or keep connections alive all the time?(about 250-300 possible clients)
Can I use Django ORM or smth like SQLAlchemy? Or even psycopg library?
Does anyone tackle such a problem before?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your case, I would rather go with Django internal implementation and follow Django ORM as you will not need to worry about handling connection and different exceptions that may arise during your own implementation of DAO model in your code.
As per your requirement, you need to access user database, there still exists overhead for individual users to create db and setup something to connect with your codebase. So, I thinking sticking with Django will be more profound.

Comment: hm. how can I create new db connection when user submits his db? editing settings file in runtime seems to be pretty bad idea

Comment: I hope I understood your problem. But, using framework is the one thing that helps to maintain internally. By default, Django will only create a new persistent database connection for every request cycle. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/databases/#persistent-connections